# How to print a word every second?

Tags: c++

How can I print a word once a second while using `fopen("filename.txt","r")`?

I searched earlier and found something that used the `unistd.h` header file, but in my Turbo C++ no such header file exists.

Comment: Turbo C++??? You have to be joking.  Couldn't get anything that existed beyond 1995?

Comment: I am a beginner :/ suggest me something better

Comment: This is entirely possible in Turbo C++, but you are going to get some weird looks. I would suggest pulling down Visual Studio Express Desktop or perhaps another more modern IDE.

Comment: @ZephyRrMahesh -  There are plenty of free, modern compilers -- Visual Studio express, gcc / Codeblocks, etc..   Also, being a beginner is no excuse really -- why would you choose such an old, outdated compiler if you wanted to learn the language?

Comment: Okay guys, I am using code blocks. Now would you mind to tell me how can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

## C++11

If your compiler supports C++11, [`std::thread::sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) is the best, cross-platform solution:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
// or
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
```

If you are forced to use compiler that doesn't support C++, you have to use platform-specific functions:

## POSIX

[`sleep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sleep.html) is part of POSIX.1-2001, so it should run on any compliant operating system, including UNIXes, Linux and Mac OS X:

```
#include <unistd.h>

sleep(1);
```

## Windows

[`Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is part of WinAPI:

```
#include <windows.h>

Sleep(1000); // Note capital "S" and that you specify time in milliseconds
```